# How i can close ng-template popup after form into popap is submitted?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

I use last Angular version and ng-bootstrap to created some popup in my main component:

```
            <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss"> 
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <app-access-form></app-access-form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close popup</button>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
```

Next, i created access-form module, like a:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #accessForm="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Статус</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required [(ngModel)]="model.status">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

if form is submutted, i try to:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.accessService.addAccess(this.model).subscribe( () );
}
```

accessService.addAccess send to API.

How i can close popup after form is submit? Can i do this in different modules or not?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the error and stacktrace?

Comment: So, have you the form inside of the popup ?

Comment: why your form it's not the modal?

Answer (score 0):

In your `component.html`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="onClick()">Close popup</button>
```

In your `component.ts`:

```
@ViewChild('div') public popover: NgbPopover;

onClick() {
    this.popover.close();
}
```

Please, check [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples) out !